# rotate custom matrix?

Tags: scripting

```
origin = Vector((1,2,3))
v = Vector((6,2,1)) - origin 

z = Vector((4,7,3)) - origin 
y = v.cross(z).normalized()
x = y.cross(z).normalized()

M = Matrix()
w1 = origin.copy()
w1.resize_4d()
M[0], M[1], M[2] ,M[3] = x.resized(4), y.resized(4), z.resized(4), w1
M.transpose()
```

The above defines a matrix

[image]

```py
M = M.Rotation(radians(10), 4, z)
```

The result is as follows

[image]

I want to rotate 10 degrees around the z axis, what is wrong?

If I want the x-axis to follow the cursor while rotating around the z-axis, how should this be achieved?